# Удалить слова из скобок не входящие в диапазон

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Я хочу с помощью regex или возможно другого способа удалять не нужные мне слова из текста.

1. Слова находятся в скобках ().
2. Могут быть пробелы после скобки или внутри между словами.
3. В тексте нет цифр или других символов кроме букв и ().
4. Может быть что одной из скобок не хватает, тогда я удаляю лишнюю.

**Пример:**

Текст на вход метода:

> Спарки (собака), очень дружелюбный (но не всегда).

Собака в скобках пусть будет разрешенным словом (собака)

Тогда на выходе я хочу получить:

> Спарки (собака), очень дружелюбный.

**Дополнил:**

Я добавил код получилось вот так:

```
 private String removeWordsInBrackets(String str) {
        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
        boolean foundBracket = false;
        for (char ch : chars) {
            if (ch == '(') {
                foundBracket = true;
            }

            if (ch == ')') {
                foundBracket = false;
                tmp.append(ch);
                if (tmp.toString().equals("(собака)")) {
                    sb.append(tmp);
                }
                tmp = new StringBuilder();
                continue;
            }

            if (foundBracket) {
                tmp.append(ch);
            } else {
                sb.append(ch);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: `String result = text.replaceAll("\\s*\\((?!собака\\))[^()]*\\)", "");`

Comment: Вам всё ещё нужен ответ? Поясните, пожалуйста, свой вопрос. Моё выражение подходит?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew подходящий код, который отбрасывает лишнее я записал в вопросе, Ваше выражение тоже частично подходит, спасибо!)

Comment: А что именно не работает, если применить мой подход? Почему частично?

Comment: Не удаляет лишние скобки, попробуйте как пример: ((собака)((кошка)
Или добавьте пару пробелов: (( собака  )((кошка)
Тогда всё сломает)

Comment: Тогда, может, `replaceAll("\\s*\\(+(?!собака\\))[^()]*\\)+","")`? https://regex101.com/r/zlqGyD/1?

Answer (score -1):

Т.к. вложенных скобок, насколько я понимаю, в вашем тексте нет - можно юзать к примеру такую регулярку:

```
\(.*?\)
```

(не забываем, что в джава-коде \ надо будет экранировать).
Если нужно менять не все слова в скобках - то сначала находите через matches, сравниваете со списком "разрешенных" слов, и которых в этом списке нет - удаляете через replace.